# pgfplots: select number of divisions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, grids

I'm not stuck to using pgfplots to produce this, so feel free to offer suggestions.

For my exam papers, I want to provide the students with blank semi-log grids to do hand plots. (To be specific, they are making Bode diagrams).

The following definition approximates the behaviour that I want. The only problem is controlling the divisions along y:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\BodeGrid{mmmm}{
\pgfplotsset{width=#1, height=#2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    xmin=1e0, xmax=1e#3,
    ymin=0, ymax=#4,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={black!50},
    yticklabels={},
    xticklabels={},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

The arguments here are the width and height, then I want to specify the number of decades along x, then the number of divisions along y. The x-axis works just fine because it will automatically produce the appropriate number of decades according to the range, if I provide an integer. The y axis, however, is at the mercy of the code which automatically divides the axis. For some range of integers (for y, the 4th argument), this command actually does what I want.

For example, \BodeGrid{\textwidth}{0.75\textheight}{3}{12} produces:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your plot is empty of actual points so `pgfplots` is smart enough to not to bother. If you pretend that you are actually drawing something it will cooperate.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\BodeGrid}[4]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=#1, height=#2,
    xmode=log,
    xmin=1e0, xmax=1e#3,
    ymin=0, ymax=#4,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={black!50},
    yticklabels={},
    xticklabels={},
    ytick={1,...,#4}
]
\addplot[draw=none,no marks] coordinates {(0,1) (1e#3,#4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
 \BodeGrid{\textwidth}{0.75\textheight}{6}{9}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize the syntax for ytick could be so nice (That is, {1,...,#4}). When I posted, I was playing with \for from tikz, which I doubt would have worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Timtro My pleasure.